# Fatal Exception AsyncTask doInBackground

Tags: android, android-asynctask

This is my main activity code but when I run the code it says unfortunately the program has stopped working. in the LogCat it says: an error occurred executing doInBackground().

And I echoed all the received json values and all are fetched and added to the array list.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.util.ArrayMap;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    private static final String URL="http://10.0.3.2/other";
    static String TITLE = "username";
    static String DESCIPTION = "password";



     @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
         new Getdata().execute();  
    }



     @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    } 

     private class  Getdata extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>{
         ProgressDialog pDialog;
         JSONParser jsp=new JSONParser();
         JSONObject job;
         ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist;
         CustomAdapter adapter;

         @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog=new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setTitle("please wait");
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading");
            pDialog.show();
        }

         @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

             List<NameValuePair> param = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
             param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", "all"));
            job= jsp.getJSONFromUrl(URL, param);

            try{
                 JSONArray jarr= job.getJSONArray("names");

                 for (int i = 0; i < jarr.length(); i++) {
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        job = jarr.getJSONObject(i);
                        // Retrive JSON Objects
                        map.put("username", job.getString("username"));
                        map.put("password", job.getString("password"));
                        Log.e("jsob", job.toString());
                        // Set the JSON Objects into the array
                        arraylist.add(map);

                    }

               }      catch(JSONException e){
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }


            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            ListView lv= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
            adapter = new CustomAdapter(MainActivity.this, arraylist);
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
            pDialog.dismiss();




        }


     }

}
```

Comment: post the whole error logcat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not initializing `arraylist`.

Answer (score 1):

I understand this doesn't directly address your issue, but I thought I should mention it anyway. It may be worth looking into using an async library.

Using a library to help handle async callbacks can be **super helpful** for this.

This is the one I usually use:

- **[LoopJ's Async HTTP Callback Library](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/)**

This will handle GET and POST requests with a lot of cool features such as custom timeouts, JSON format, onSuccess() and onFailure() methods, etc. There's a lot of working examples of this library too. I've used it in all my apps and haven't had any problems yet!

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: hey that was great but i don't have enough time to read and cope up with that . like hours time line so please if you could see it and give me some more advices..